# Need Help - Clicking on a image to set the status of a field

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, css

Basically, when someone submits information to the database, it fills in all of the fields **but status.**

Status(The field) is meant to be determined by the administration team which signs into  the "Faction Leader" panel.

Basically my intentions are so that the checkmark image is clicked(checkmark.png), it sets 'status' to accepted. When the X image is clicked(x.png), it sets **status** to denied within the MySQL database.

**Here is a screenie of what I have set up so far for a application:**

[image]

As stated, everything is under the table "Data".

ID is a progressing row, which increases by a variable of 1 per entry.

**Important web pages:**

http://www.anonymousresources.co.cc/IngameApplication/home.php - The home page for the project. It's where the user submits his application, and where a user is linked to for faction administration.

http://www.anonymousresources.co.cc/IngameApplication/newviewdata.php - New page I'm working on for the viewdata, it's unlocked on purpose. You can view it without signing in at the moment.

**Note:**  I did have a nice design for this post which I worked all night on, but they wouldn't let me use images apparently because I'm new :/

Comment: Your image should show up now.

Comment: What is actually being asked here, specifically? I can't tell if you need HTML, CSS, PHP, MySQL, or javascript help.

Comment: Asking how to make it so when you click the image, it changes a value of the corrosponding id in the MySQL database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want to update your status in database clicking on image then you can do it using jquery/Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("yourImageId").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url : "your_url_for_function_to_update_status",
       data: "id="+your_row_id_which_status_u_want_change,
       success: function(resp) {
          alert(resp);
       }
    });
  });
});
And in your "your_url_for_function_to_update_status" in php you can get post value and updte accordingly
```

Hope it helps you in some sense